# Evaluating the series $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{n}{3^n}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, geometric-series

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find the sum of this infinite series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30732/how-to-find-the-sum-of-this-infinite-series)

Hello all, I have one last major question, where would I get started on the following question:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{n}{3^n}$$

I know it is a series (obviously), and I think it is geometric, but I have no idea as to how to start it.  Does anyone have any first steps/tips as to what I could do for this?

Thanks so much in advance!

**Edit:**
Per the first comment on my posting, by 1hf, see:

Very close to [How can I evaluate $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+1)x^n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30732/how-to-find-the-sum-of-this-infinite-series)

In particular, see the answer at [How can I evaluate $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+1)x^n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30732/how-to-find-the-sum-of-this-infinite-series/30747#30747)

Thanks all!

Comment: Very close to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30732/how-to-find-the-sum-of-this-infinite-series . In particular, see the answer at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30732/how-to-find-the-sum-of-this-infinite-series/30747#30747

Comment: Thanks! If you put that in a answer form, I can give you credit for the answer easier :)

Answer (score 6):

**Hint:** Observe that $$(\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n)'=\sum_{n=0}^\infty nx^{n-1}$$ and $\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n$ is convergent for all $|x|<1$

Answer (score 4):

Let $S_n=\sum_{k=0}^n k/3^k$. Simplify $3 S_{n+1} - S_n$ to determine $S_n$ and then take the limit as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: I get $3 S_{n+1} - S_n = 2 S_n + \frac{n+1}{3^n}$, in the limit this is $2S = 2S$... How do you get the sum?

Comment: I get $3S_{n+1}−S_n = \sum_{k=0}^n 1/3^k$

Answer (score 3):

It's (not quite) geometric.  A geometric series is of the form $\sum_{n = 0}^\infty x^n$.

You are on the right track.  For a geometric series, provided $|x|<1$, 
$$\sum_{n = 0}^\infty x^n = \frac{1}{1 - x}.$$

For convergent series, it's acceptable to differentiate term by term.  This tells us, provided $|x| < 1$,
$$\sum_{n = 0}^\infty nx^{n-1} = \left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)' = \frac{1}{(1-x)^2}.$$

I claim your series is very close, but not quite, equal to this form with $x = 1/3$.